# display dynamic table after clicking submit button

Tags: php

Sir,

I have a form which contains 3 text fields and a submit button.(basically a search form) I made a query set through which i dynamically display a table on the same page. So inputting a specific data in any of the text field and hitting the submit button the table shows the relevant result for that query. 
  Now when the page loads it shows the empty table also. I want when user enters some txt inputs and hits submit button then only the table below should shows up. Please help me. I am totally new to coding. I uses dreamweaver.

Comment: put your code so that we can help you.

Comment: Unless you want to store the data in a database or something similar, use JavaScript. It's far easier for many reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
      if(isset(POST['submit']))
      {
           ?>
           Set table structure here ....
           <?php  
      }
?>
```

-
Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much I used <?php
      if (isset($_POST['submit']))
      {
           ?> Set table structure here ....
           <?php  
      }
?> it works, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<title>Test</title>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" name="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table width="100%" align="center">
<tr><td>First Name</td><TD><input type="text" name="fname"></TD></tr>
<tr><td></td><TD><input type="text" name="mname"></TD></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name</td><TD><input type="text" name="lname"> </TD></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onmouseover="this.style.cursor=\'pointer\';" OnMouseOut="this.style.cursor=\'default\';">
</td></tr></table></form> 
<?PHP
if(isset(POST['submit']))
{
    $con = mysql_connect("$host","$username","$pass"); 
    if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("$db_name", $con); //database name
    mysql_query("insert into db_table set first_name='".$POST['fname']."',middle_name='".$POST['mname']."',last_name='".$POST['lname']."'");
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_table"); //table

    echo "<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
    <tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Middle Name</th>
     <th>Last Name</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['middle_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['last_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysql_close($con);
}
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not provide any code, I guess you can do something like this :-

If your search result return null then don't show the table :-

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) <= 0)
{
   //don't show your table
}
else
{
  // result table
}
```